# Criando mensagem custimizada de autorização

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Tem alguma forma de customizar a mensagem de autorização para `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` e `requestAlwaysAuthorization`?

Sei que para isso funcionar temos que adicionar no `info.plist` as informações `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` e `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

Mas queria montar um `alertview` customizado para meu `app` ao invés de utilizar o `alertview` padrão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, você não pode customizar a mensagem nativa so iOS para pedir as autorizações de localização.

O que eu sugiro você fazer é criar esse `UIAlertView` com a mensagem que você quer e mostrá-lo antes do `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` ou `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, porém serão exibidos os dois alertas.